# Get values of input buttons with comma separated string in hidden input

Tags: javascript, jquery, button

I have 5 input button with values.

```
<input class="btn btn-default baths" name="baths"  type="button" value="1">
<input class="btn btn-default baths" name="baths"  type="button" value="2">
<input class="btn btn-default baths" name="baths"  type="button" value="3">
<input class="btn btn-default baths" name="baths"  type="button" value="4">
<input class="btn btn-default baths" name="baths"  type="button" value="5+">
```

I want this all button values in the hidden input field on click and if the user clicks that button again then the value of that button is also getting disappear from the hidden field.

```
<input class="all_baths" type="hidden" value="">
```

Count me as a beginner in the jquery and all.

I have tried this jquery but not get the proper result. I get all values on single click of all button in hidden field.

```
$('input.baths').click(function () {
    $value = $('input.baths').map(function () {
        return $(this).val()
    }).get().join(',');

    $('input.all_baths').val($value);
});
```

What I want in the hidden field is like

```
<input class="all_baths" type="hidden" value="1,3,4">
```

Comment: You want to place the value of clicked element on the hidden input element?

Comment: @Ayush yes sir.

Comment: thanks to all of you for help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pure JS solution:

**Note**: I have deleted the `hidden` type from the input to make the results visible.

```js
var elems = document.getElementsByName('baths'),
    hidden = document.getElementById('hidden'),
    values = [];
    
Array.from(elems).forEach(v => v.addEventListener('click', function() {
  values.indexOf(this.value) == -1 ? values.push(this.value) : values.splice(values.indexOf(this.value), 1);
  hidden.value = values.sort((a,b) => a.match(/\d+/) - b.match(/\d+/));
}));
```

```html
<input class="btn btn-default baths" name="baths" type="button" value="1">
<input class="btn btn-default baths" name="baths" type="button" value="2">
<input class="btn btn-default baths" name="baths" type="button" value="3">
<input class="btn btn-default baths" name="baths" type="button" value="4">
<input class="btn btn-default baths" name="baths" type="button" value="5+">

<input class="all_baths" type="" value="" id='hidden'>
```

Comment: No sir, this is not i am looking for. I am looking for like this.                                          <input type=hidden valuse="2,3,4">

Comment: Sir Your suggested solution is perfect but when  I  put this in my code it's not working.  can you help me over this? I put the code between the script where other scripts are. @Kind user

Comment: @ankitsuthar What browser are you using?

Comment: Google Crome Sir.

Comment: @ankitsuthar It's should work then. Try to move your script from the bottom of the `body` tag into the `head` tag or vice versa and check if it works. I'm going to my work now, if you will still have problems I will help you when I'm in my work. I will contact you.

Comment: I got sir,  I get the string. thank you very much, sir @Kinduser

Answer (score 1):

Do the inputs **have** to be of type `button`? It is possible to do this with type `checkbox` quite easily.

```js
$('.baths').on('change', function() {
    var vals = [];
    $('.baths:checked').each(function(){ //could also use .map here
        vals.push($(this).val());
    });
    $('.all_baths').val(vals.join(','));
    console.log($('.all_baths').val());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="btn btn-default baths" name="baths"  type="checkbox" value="1">
<input class="btn btn-default baths" name="baths"  type="checkbox" value="2">
<input class="btn btn-default baths" name="baths"  type="checkbox" value="3">
<input class="btn btn-default baths" name="baths"  type="checkbox" value="4">
<input class="btn btn-default baths" name="baths"  type="checkbox" value="5+">

<input class="all_baths" type="hidden" value="">
```

Otherwise - you need to keep track of what's been clicked on in an array:

```js
var baths = [],
    $baths = $('.baths'),
    $all_baths = $('.all_baths');
$baths.on('click', function(){
    var $this = $(this),
        val = $this.val();
    //Already added - remove it
    if(baths.indexOf(val) > -1) {
      baths.splice(baths.indexOf(val), 1);
    }
    //not added - add it
    else {
        baths.push(val);
    }
    
    $all_baths.val(baths.join(','));
    console.log($all_baths.val());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="btn btn-default baths" name="baths"  type="button" value="1">
<input class="btn btn-default baths" name="baths"  type="button" value="2">
<input class="btn btn-default baths" name="baths"  type="button" value="3">
<input class="btn btn-default baths" name="baths"  type="button" value="4">
<input class="btn btn-default baths" name="baths"  type="button" value="5+">

<input class="all_baths" type="hidden" value="">
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var baths = []
$('input.baths').click(function() {

  //$(".btn.baths").each(function(){

  baths.push($(this).val())
  //})

  $(".all_baths").val(baths)
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="btn btn-default baths" name="baths" type="button" value="1">
<input class="btn btn-default baths" name="baths" type="button" value="2">
<input class="btn btn-default baths" name="baths" type="button" value="3">
<input class="btn btn-default baths" name="baths" type="button" value="4">
<input class="btn btn-default baths" name="baths" type="button" value="5+">


<input class="all_baths" type="hidden" value="">
```

Add the click value on an array on click of button

Comment: I have tried your answer but the same issue, i get all the values in hidden input with single click on any button which i don't want. I want only that button values which are get clicked.

Comment: dont add the value in array i misunderstood your question

Comment: @ankitsuthar check again

Comment: I don't like this approach in particular since you're creating an array.

Answer (score 0):

Try this exactly what you want

```js
var baths = [];
$('input[name="baths"]').click(function () {
debugger;
$('input[name="baths"]').each(function() {
      $value = $(this).val();
baths.push($(this).val())
});
if($('input.all_baths').val()){
$('input.all_baths').val("");
 baths=[];
}
else{
$('input.all_baths').val(baths.join(','));

}
    
});
```

```html
<input class="btn btn-default baths" name="baths"  type="button" value="1">
<input class="btn btn-default baths" name="baths"  type="button" value="2">
<input class="btn btn-default baths" name="baths"  type="button" value="3">
<input class="btn btn-default baths" name="baths"  type="button" value="4">
<input class="btn btn-default baths" name="baths"  type="button" value="5+">

<input class="all_baths" type="" value="">

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this code will work for you. When you click on a button the value will be added to the `hidden` field and when you click it again the value will be removed from the `hidden` field as you told you want.

```
<input class="btn btn-default baths" name="baths"  type="button" value="1">
<input class="btn btn-default baths" name="baths"  type="button" value="2">
<input class="btn btn-default baths" name="baths"  type="button" value="3">
<input class="btn btn-default baths" name="baths"  type="button" value="4">
<input class="btn btn-default baths" name="baths"  type="button" value="5+">

<input class="all_baths" type="hidden" value="">
```

**JQuery Code**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.baths').on('click', function () {
          var current = $(this).val();
          var prev = $('.all_baths').val();
          console.log("current "+current+ " prev="+prev);

          if (prev === "") {
                $('.all_baths').val(current); //If hidden field is empty then add first value
          } else {
            var current = $(this).val();
            var arr = prev.toString().split(',');
            if ($.inArray(current, arr) != -1) {
              arr.splice(arr.indexOf(current),1); //If value already present then remove it
            } else {
              arr.push(current); // If value not present already then add it
            }
            console.log("array "+arr);
            $('.all_baths').val(arr.join(",").toString()); // Add the final array to hidden field
          }

      });

});
```

[Working JS fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9x41eg20/4/)

You can look at the comments to understand the code. I hope it helps you out.